# SharePoint user profile still showing old information

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, active-directory

A user was promoted to management however his profile is still showing his previous profile information.  So whenever you see his ID in the SharePoint sites entries or uploads, it shows his old profile (Mbr to Mgr).  Is there a solution for this?  I saw online that it's as simple as going to this site and make one entry or upload and within a couple of hours, the change would show...something about syncing.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use the below powershell command to update the user infomation:

```
Set-SPUser -Identity 'Contoso\michael' -Web http://yoursite -SyncFromAD
```

Read here for more：

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/set-spuser?view=sharepoint-ps

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration > Service Applications > User Profile Service > run a Full synchronisation to give it a good update ** This may be scheduled to only run one a week, should be daily at a maximum

Whilst in UPS above, user Manage Profile and search for the user to determine if details have been updated in the master list, if so and still not updated in the site collection, the issues is something other than the AD sync.